# Determine whether App is visible when clicking on a notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have a foreground service, which can be stopped by clicking on a "X" in the notification.

When the foreground service is stopped an other activity should be shown.

The problem is, I don't know whether the app is visible or in the background when the "X"-Button is clicked. When the app is visible the activity should be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check about your activity whether its running in foreground or not? Here you go :

```
public boolean isRunning(Context ctx) {
    try {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    // The first in the list of RunningTasks is always the foreground
    // task.
    RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
    String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity
            .getPackageName();// get the top fore ground activity
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(
            foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);

    String foregroundTaskAppName = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo
            .loadLabel(pm).toString();

    // Log.e("", foregroundTaskAppName +"----------"+
    // foregroundTaskPackageName);
    if (!foregroundTaskAppName.equals("Your App name")) {
        return true;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("isAppSentToBackground", "" + e);
}
return false;
}
```

For API level >= 21

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = activityManager.getAppTasks();

for (ActivityManager.AppTask task : tasks) {
    Log.d(TAG, "stackId: " + task.getTaskInfo().stackId);
}
```

Comment: If if the activity is running in the background I am getting 2 Tasks, one for the Service and one for the activity. Only when the activity is killed by the os there is only one task.

Comment: @sativa : Yes, here you have to check whatever the first task in the stack will be always in foreground

Comment: @sativa This code would not work for Andoid API Level >= 21 as the method is deprecated [API Docs Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int))

Comment: @harsh201 : Thanks for the point to be mentioned! I updated the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% guaranty solution for your problem.

One of the most simple is to track visible activity at global variable :

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    App.visibleActivity = this; 
}

public void onPause(){
   super.onPause();
   App.visibleActivity = null;
}
```

But there are some important things:

1) dont forgot to free visibleActivity at  onPause to prevent memory leak

2) there is a time gap between current onPause and the next onResume when your app is technically in background